# Get full rails controller name, including the namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've many controllers in different namespaces. The controller_name method only returns the name of the controller, e.g. 'articles'.
Is there any chance to get the full name like 'service/articles' (the articles controller is in the service namespace)?

I want do create a link to the index action of each controller via a globally used partial:

```
<%= link_to controller.display_name, { :controller => controller.controller_name, :action => "index"} %>
```

If this partial is rendered in a view in the 'users' namespace, I get an error: users/articles has no route (it should be service/articles).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
controller_path
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Base.html#method-i-controller_path

Comment: Ahh thanks. With
%= link_to item.display_name, { :controller => '/' + item.controller_path, :action => "index"} it works.

Comment: In more recent versions of Rails, this should be `controller.controller_path`.

Comment: I've been a Rails developer for over 10 years and you taught me something new today!  There's a method for everything!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of linking to the :controller, :action syntax, can you use nested resources

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources: articles
end
```

**in your view**

```
= link_to 'Articles', user_article_path(current_user)
```

The user_article will take care of your namespaces for you.

Comment: But this requires that I need to add each resource as a nested resource to all other resources. I need to link from users to articles, articles to users, downloads to articles, downloads to users... across different namespaces. Nested resources seems not to be a good solution.

Comment: Another problem: The partial is used by all views and processes a list of ControllerClasses to create links to these controllers. At this point, I can't write user_article_path(current_user) here, because this depends on the current controller/view.