# getting the namespace of a rails controller object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

What is the best way to get the current controller object's namespace?  From inspecting self in a current controller action, I see there is a parameter "REQUEST_URI" that contains a string like "foo_namespace/bar", but I was wondering if there is a better way to get it than to get that (that request_uri wasn't even accessible directly from the controller instance object, I think it was nested in some other params)?

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273503/get-full-rails-controller-name-including-the-namespace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are able to do `params[:controller].split("/").first`. This will return that namespace.

Answer (score 8):

In both the controller and the views, you can parse controller_path, eg.:

```
namespace = controller_path.split('/').first
```